# Bootstrap AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, django, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to use Carousel (ui.bootstrap.carousel) bootstrap. I just simply copied the codes given and added it into my project. But it's not working as expected.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
  <div style="height: 305px">
    <carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
      <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>Slide {{ $index }}</h4>
          <p>{{ slide.text }}</p>
        </div>
      </slide>
    </carousel>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addSlide()">Add Slide</button>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="noWrapSlides">
          Disable Slide Looping
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Interval, in milliseconds: <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="myInterval">
      <br />Enter a negative number or 0 to stop the interval.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and app.js

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myInterval = 5000;
  $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
  var slides = $scope.slides = [];
  $scope.addSlide = function() {
    var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
    slides.push({
      image: '//placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
      text: ['More','Extra','Lots of','Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
        ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]
    });
  };
  for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    $scope.addSlide();
  }
});
```

But I am getting an error as follows. Can someone explain to me what is index is. Am using Django frame work in my project. Thats the root cause of the problem. Please help me on it, thanks in advance.

[image]

I have used `{%load verbatim%}`. But I got an error as "'verbatim' is not a valid tag library: Template library verbatim not found, tried django.templatetags.verbatim,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.verbatim,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.verbatim."

Comment: Looks like you have a conflict with django trying to compile angular templates. `$index` is used in angular `ng-repeat` and is index of individual items in the repater

Comment: yeah. Thinks the same. What how can i fix it?

Comment: Simplest would be not have django involved with view . Or find settings for it to not compile view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used verbatim again as follows. Now its working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/app.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
{%verbatim%}
<body>

<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
    <div style="height: 30px">
        <carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
            <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>Slide {{$loggedin}}</h4>
                    <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
                </div>

            </slide>
        </carousel>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="row">-->
        <!--<div class="col-md-6">-->
            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addSlide()">Add Slide</button>-->
        <!--</div>-->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
{%endverbatim%}
</html>
```